# spamassassin adding blank lines when wrapping long headers: how to make it stop?

Tags: spamassasin

My email from Kickstarter started showing up in my mailbox corrupted. On investigation, it turns out to because I have these diagnostic headers added in my spamassassin config:

```
add_header all What-Looks-Spammy _SPAMMYTOKENS(7,short)_
add_header all What-Looks-Hammy  _HAMMYTOKENS(7,short)_
```

It turns out that there are several graphic files that Kickstarter links to, the names of which SA has determined to be the most hammy tokens. However, these names are very long. The net effect is that my header ends up getting inserted like this:

```
X-Spam-What-Looks-Hammy: UD:kickstarter-logo-130-c786b4c0131e4675d4e938b400dcb05d64f7709750ad31d54a87555a0e83dab8.png,

        UD:twitter-social-7e6088443f29898180e0f5cfaab62693049355b9822ffb9ae89c186296592238.png,

        facebooksocial675e657a12f1b904b75c03a78b01a43b0a5b8768803a712e3e0fc623fe0563b5png,

        twitter-social-7e6088443f29898180e0f5cfaab62693049355b9822ffb9ae89c186296592238.png,

        UD:facebook-social-675e657a12f1b904b75c03a78b01a43b0a5b8768803a712e3e0fc623fe0563b5.png,

        kickstarterlogo130c786b4c0131e4675d4e938b400dcb05d64f7709750ad31d54a87555a0e83dab8png,

        kickstarter-logo-130-c786b4c0131e4675d4e938b400dcb05d64f7709750ad31d54a87555a0e83dab8.png
```

with those blank lines included. Since a blank line signifies the end of the headers, no wonder everything is confused. This happens if I just run the raw message through spamc on the command line, so I'm confident that it's nothing else in my procmail chain.

How can I stop this, without disabling the header?

Comment: I've seen wierd file viewers / whatever that can't handle long lines without spaces which are also indented; those are displayed with extra blank lines. Actually those blank lines aren't there. Please run `cat -ve` on the mailbox to see what those lines actually look like.

Comment: @wurtel The lines actually are like that. (If they weren't, then there wouldn't be a problem in the mail client.)